# env variable undefined in create react app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I'm trying to use environment variables in my react app that I created with npx create-react-app.
I created .env file(in the root directory) and placed the variable which start with REACT_APP, but still when I try to log it in the console, it shows up undefined.

I did restart development server many times, still the same.

[image]

[image]

I uploaded test project [here](https://workupload.com/file/B4FXKJ8HJRL)

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the reason behind this, but it did not work for me with the .env file in the attachment.
So i deleted the .env file and created new one will same content and it started working

[image]

Comment: yes,    console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_IP);

Comment: also sorry for  the silly question, restart means stoping the npm start and starting it again by doing npm start.

Comment: Yes that how I do it

Comment: This one is really tough , as its very specific to your app in your local machine.

Ideally it should work. not sure, if anyone could help.

Comment: you can check out the code here -> https://workupload.com/file/B4FXKJ8HJRL

Comment: It did work for mee too. Originally I created the file with echo  command and that was the reason(I dont know why). Now I did it regularly with vs code and it works.